# Dynamic condition in LIKE clause in a Hive query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Generally when I apply LIKE condition in a hive query I apply a static condition like this-

```
select * from table where col1 like '%abc%';
```

I have a use case where I want the LIKE condition to be dynamic, I want the parameter '%abc%' to come from a column in another hive table, so something like this-

```
select * from table where col1 like (select regex from table2);
```

Is there anyway I can do this in Hive?

Generally in SQL I can do it through a join with LIKE condition but as far as I know Hive only allows equality joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least the more recent versions of Hive support non-equijoins (see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins)).

So, you should be able to do:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     table2 t2
     on t.col1 like t2.regex;
```

Do note that `like` patterns are not equivalent to regular expressions.
where col1 like (select regex from table2);